# call a javascript method from cshtml view

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to add a javascript code to `cshtml` view like this :

```
@model MySolution.webApi.Models.ReservationModel
<script src="~/Scripts/DemandeClient/DetailCourse.js"></script>
<body onload="Loading(@Model)">
...........
</body>
```

In the **javascript file**

```
function Loading(data) {
    console.log(data);
                       }
```

the problem is that I get the type of the model without its value, I tried to replace the second line by

```
<body onload="Loading('@Model')">
```

But I get the same result.

So How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [**Json.Encode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method to converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format. Then you can use the variable as per need.

```
<script>
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    Loading(model);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize your model to json, however it simpler to just assign it to a javascript variable inside your `<script>` tags

```
var m = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```